# Flutter plugin for automated emails?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a flutter plugin for sending automated emails in the background (ie without opening email app and having user hit send)? Basically I’d like to be able to pass a sender email, receiver email, subject, body,etc.
I know plugins such as: [https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mailer](http://%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mailer)
exist but I don't believe they allow for a custom sender email.

If this plugin doesn’t exist yet, how could one go about building it? I would love to build it out if possible , thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a way to do this currently. The issue with doing this will be that you need the users email credentials in order to send email on their behalf. The only other way to go about doing this would be to send email using an account controlled by you, but the downside to that is that all email would come from that one specific account, regardless of user.

Comment: Thanks first for your response .
Secondly, I really did not find a solution for it yet. I really do have the way that you thought it now, but unfortunately it does not make sense.
I hope someone will help us in this matter.